# How to sum a sequence in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to do some coding in python and I can't do this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Interview':['1','1','2','2','3','3','4','4','5','5'],
                 'Sequence':['1st','2nd','1st','2nd','1st','2nd','1st','2nd','1st','2nd'],
                 'Product':['Orange','Banana','Banana','Orange','Apple','Banana','Apple','Apple','Orange','Apple'],
                  'Value':[6,8,5,4,3,5,7,6,7,9]})
```

[image: Pandas sample]

I need to do something like this as result:

```
sequence = pd.DataFrame({'1st':['Orange','Orange','Orange','Banana','Banana','Banana','Apple','Apple','Apple'],
                       '2nd':['Orange','Banana','Apple','Orange','Banana','Apple','Orange','Banana','Apple'],
                       'Value':[0,14,16,9,0,0,0,8,13]})
```

[image: Pandas sample result]

For me the sequence matters most in my analysis. It's a sum of the  results in interviews.

Thanks guys  for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach using `reindex` and `unstack`:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['Interview', 'Sequence']).unstack()
result = df2.Product.join(df2.Value.sum(1).rename("Value"))

#               1st     2nd  Value
# Interview                       
# 1          Orange  Banana     14
# 2          Banana  Orange      9
# 3           Apple  Banana      8
# 4           Apple   Apple     13
# 5          Orange   Apple     16
```

Answer (score 2):

This does it.  Basically, you extract the rows matching "1st" and "2nd", then reindex them, then rebuild a new data frame with those columns.  And if someone can tell me how to extract just the values of those series without requiring the re-index and drop column hackery, I'd appreciate it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Interview':['1','1','2','2','3','3','4','4','5','5'],
    'Sequence':['1st','2nd','1st','2nd','1st','2nd','1st','2nd','1st','2nd'],
    'Product':['Orange','Banana','Banana','Orange','Apple','Banana','Apple','Apple','Orange','Apple'],
    'Value':[6,8,5,4,3,5,7,6,7,9]}
)
s1 = df[df['Sequence']=='1st']['Value'].reset_index()['Value'] 
s2 = df[df['Sequence']=='2nd']['Value'].reset_index()['Value']
p1 = df[df['Sequence']=='1st']['Product'].reset_index()['Product'] 
p2 = df[df['Sequence']=='2nd']['Product'].reset_index()['Product']
out = pd.DataFrame( { '1st': p1, '2nd': p2, 'Sum': s1+s2 } )
print(out)
```

Output:

```
      1st     2nd  Sum
0  Orange  Banana   14
1  Banana  Orange    9
2   Apple  Banana    8
3   Apple   Apple   13
4  Orange   Apple   16
```